# How to sort std::pair first only?

Tags: c++, sorting

I have task to make method that:

- get numbers from string
- every number is equal to its summed sub-numbers
- now sort these sums
- display the sorted sums and their original values

I made that function:

```
void orderWeight(const std::string &strng)
{
    std::vector<pair<int, int>> result;
    int r{}, rr{}, rrr{};
    std::stringstream ss(strng);

    while(ss>>r){
            rrr = r;
        while(r!=0){
            rr += r%10;
            r /= 10;
        }
        result.push_back( make_pair(rr, rrr));

        rr = 0;
        r = 0;
    }

    std::sort( result.begin(), result.end());

    for( int i=0; i<result.size();i++){
        cout<<result[i].first<<" "<<result[i].second<<endl;
    }
}
```

This function for arguments - `56 65 74 100 99 68 86 180 90` returns :

```
1 100
9 90
9 180
11 56
11 65
11 74
14 68
14 86
18 99
```

But I don't want to sort it by first value THEN by second as You can see in

```
9 90
9 180
```

If two numbers are the same, don't sort them by second value, just how are they in a string.

How can I make it happen?

Comment: You can pass a custom comparator to std::sort https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort

Comment: I think you may need to use `std::stable_sort` alongside a custom sorting comparator if keeping the original order between equal items is important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make it happen by providing a predicate to `sort` that tells it *how* to sort. For example, a simple lambda:

```
std::sort( result.begin(), result.end(),
    [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) {
        return lhs.first < rhs.first;
    });
```

The above will sort *only* by the first value.

See also: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort

Comment: @Jarod42 If that matters one should use `std::stable_sort`.